# How to integrate PHP Twilio Video in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php, twilio-video

How will can I integrate this quickstart app (https://github.com/twilio/twilio-video-app-react) in a wordpress application as a separate application. Something like when you click the button in wordpress you go to Twilio video with some GET parameters.

Can I just upload the twilio video folder in wordpress root directory and customized the GET parameters, or is there any way around?